# Custom Ansible module is giving param extra params error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-module

I am trying to implement hostname like module and my target machine in an amazon-ec2. But When I am running the script its giving me below error:

```
[ansible-user@ansible-master ~]$ ansible node1 -m edit_hostname.py -a node2
ERROR! this task 'edit_hostname.py' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: meta, group_by, add_host, include_tasks, import_role, raw, set_fact, command, win_shell, import_tasks, script, shell, include_vars, include_role, include, win_command
```

My module is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json


def write_to_file(module, hostname, hostname_file):

    try:
        with open(hostname_file, 'w+') as f:
            try:
                f.write("%s\n" %hostname)
            finally:
                f.close()
    except Exception:
        err = get_exception()
        module.fail_json(msg="failed to write to the /etc/hostname file")

def main():

    hostname_file = '/etc/hostname'
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=dict(name=dict(required=True, type=str)))
    name = module.params['name']
    write_to _file(module, name, hostname_file)
    module.exit_json(changed=True, meta=name)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

I don't know where I am making the mistake. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When developing a new module, I would recommend to use the [boilerplate described in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#starting-a-new-module). This also shows that you'll need to use `AnsibleModule` to define your arguments.

In your `main`, you should add something like the following:

```
def main():
    # define available arguments/parameters a user can pass to the module
    module_args = dict(
        name=dict(type='str', required=True)
    )

    # seed the result dict in the object
    # we primarily care about changed and state
    # change is if this module effectively modified the target
    # state will include any data that you want your module to pass back
    # for consumption, for example, in a subsequent task
    result = dict(
        changed=False,
        original_hostname='',
        hostname=''
    )

    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec=module_args
        supports_check_mode=False
    )

    # manipulate or modify the state as needed (this is going to be the
    # part where your module will do what it needs to do)
    result['original_hostname'] = module.params['name']
    result['hostname'] = 'goodbye'

    # use whatever logic you need to determine whether or not this module
    # made any modifications to your target
    result['changed'] = True

    # in the event of a successful module execution, you will want to
    # simple AnsibleModule.exit_json(), passing the key/value results
    module.exit_json(**result)
```

Then, you can call the module like so:

```
ansible node1 -m mymodule.py -a "name=myname"
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR! this task 'edit_hostname.py' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: meta, group_by, add_host, include_tasks, import_role, raw, set_fact, command, win_shell, import_tasks, script, shell, include_vars, include_role, include, win_command

As explained by your error message, an anonymous default parameter is only supported by a limited number of modules. In your custom module, the paramter you created is called `name`. Moreover, you should not include the `.py` extension in the module name. You have to call your module like so as an ad-hoc command:

```
$ ansible node1 -m edit_hostname -a name=node2
```

I did not test your module code so you may have further errors to fix.

Meanwhile, I still strongly suggest you use the default boilerplate from the ansible documentation as proposed in @Simon's answer.